# Why is "For Sell" replacing "For Sale" in common usage?

Tags: word-choice

I absolutely cringe when I read advertisements offering items "For Sell" rather than "For Sale."

I do not claim to have a good command of grammar, spelling, or appropriate American English usage.  I did work hard to acquire the limited skills I posses, and so it bothers me deeply when I regularly read "Sale" in place of "Sell" in ad.  What happened?  Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe it is Spanglish, with there now being so many people in the US whose first language is Spanish, and with the WSJ recently reporting that 10% of US job seekers have limited English ability.

Comment: Can you show some evidence of these ads? I've never seen one.

Comment: @curiousdannii Here's a [Nairaland advert](http://www.nairaland.com/1048160/nokia-6120c-phone-sell-clean) from Nigeria. Click the link at your own risk.

Comment: @AndrewLeach that was . . . quite something.

Comment: I saw my sister using that, since she's not exactly bright in English (we're Indonesians) I thought it's just another case of particularly bad Engrish, but if this has been spotted in "common usage" maybe English language is starting to crumble

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that this is an issue of pronunciation creeping into the written word. If you found the authors of those "for sell" ads and talked to them for a while, you would likely find they pronounce the word 'sale' the way they spelled it: 'sell'. Also likely: they are not voracious readers.

Comment: This sounds plausible to me. As a child, my sister consistently pronounced _-ale_ and _-ail_ words (like _whale_ and _fail_) as if they were spelled _-ell_ (like _whell_ and _fell_). She didn't have trouble with any other pronunciation, but she had to go to speech therapy for a while to get her _whales_ and _fails_ right. I wonder if _-ale/-ell_ confusion is recognized as a particular phonetic difficulty, and whether there is a name for it at this level of granularity.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common in Utah, where I live. In the local accent, "sale" is pronounced like "sell" and "whale" like "well."